# Is NSOrderedSet faster than NSSet?

Tags: arrays, swift

Is NSOrderedSet faster than NSSet? Has anyone done any tests where on is better over the other? If not why was NSOrderedSet introduced in the first place?

Comment: What did your testing suggest? Especially as regards inserting items.

Comment: It has to do with how Objective-C and Cocoa are designed and inherently with mutability. Instead of writing a lengthy answer, I suggest you check something like http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't see any difference to be honest. But again, my dataset was not that big. Just over 6000 records.

Answer (score 1):

#### NSOrderedSet

The point of using an ordered set is that it is traversable in its original order in which items were added to it, and querying whether an object is contained is faster than for an unordered array. The "contains" operation (and set operations that build on it) is however slower than the O(1) that's possible with an unordered set for that operation.

#### Unordered set

The point of a set is that it allows for a best case O(1) "contains" query time. It is the data structure you should use out of these two when you need as fast "contains" time and do not need to retrieve the items in the structure in any specified sort order.

It is internally probably implemented as a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), although it's not pointed out in the Foundation documentation.

I'd advise reading [this great blog post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/79850/collection-data-structures-swift) regarding the different uses of the different Foundation data structures.